# To or for usage: Places

Tags: word-usage, toponyms

Which of these is correct?

> She is leaving *for* the USA.

or

> She is leaving *to* the USA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"She is leaving **for** the USA" is correct. The alternative is ungrammatical.

Comment: +1. But note that "She is going **to** the USA."